# New Ember.js app in shared folder of VMware Ubuntu guest

Tags: npm, ember.js, ember-cli, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am trying to develop an Ember.js app in VMware. The scenario is the following:

- Host: Windows 7 Pro.
- Guest: Ubuntu Server 18.04.

After installation of Ember.js, "ember -v" returns:

```
ember-cli: 3.15.1
node: 12.14.0
os: linux x64
```

If i try to create a new Ember app from my home directory there is no problem but, as I want to edit files from Windows host OS, when I try to do the same (ember new app_name) in the shared folder (/mnt/hgfs/folder_name/) an error is thrown:

```
Error creating new application. Removing generated directory `./app_name`
Command failed: npm install --loglevel error
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.4.1: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.4: Please replace with usage of fs.existsSync
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /mnt/hgfs/folder_name/app_name/node_modules/.acorn-dynamic-import.DELETE/node_modules/acorn
npm ERR! dest /mnt/hgfs/folder_name/app_name/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/mnt/hgfs/folder_name/app_name/node_modules/.acorn-dynamic-import.DELETE/node_modules/acorn' -> '/mnt/hgfs/folder_name/app_name/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-01-03T21_43_21_623Z-debug.log


Stack Trace and Error Report: /tmp/error.dump.1e44562d410bb23303e1023cf42f30f8.log
```

I tried the following solution from https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

```
# Make a directory for global installations:
mkdir ~/.npm-global

# Configure npm to use the new directory path:
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

#Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

#Back on the command line, update your system variables:
source ~/.profile
```

But no success.

Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: probably this is no good idea anyway because the shared folder is slow. Have you considered to use the home folder and use vscode remote ssh to edit the files from windows?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with NPM not with Ember CLI. The [official recommended solution](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/appendix/common-issues/#cygwinonwindows) is either use Ember CLI on windows or the Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL). Any reason you are not using one of these?

Comment: WSL is not avaliable on Windows 7

Comment: I tried to use VM with shared folder but encountered similar issues. I believe it has something to do with permissions in shared folder (NTFS does not support permissions system that Ext4 supports). I suggest to use dual boot (install Linux as second OS). If you don't want to do that, full VM with GUI and its own virtual drive works for development too (performance would not be as good, though)

Comment: I agree with @GennadyDogaev. It seems to be something related to permissions with that shared folder because there is no problem in any other folder. There are many discussions about creating symlinks in shared folder. Perhaps that is the reason of failure.

Comment: I have tried @Lux 's suggestion using vscode remote ssh (SSH FS extension) and, so far, everything works fine. I hope performance not be a new issue. My intention is, once the app is running in VMware Ubuntu guest, export it directly.

Comment: Just as you cannot switch npm versions without doing another npm install, you cannot switch operating systems without doing the same. The ember binary compiled in Linux won't run in Windows and vice versa. Symlinks created in Linux do not work in Windows and vice versa. The simplest solution is to erase your node_modules and npm install again.